# Tricky problem on function equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

> How do you evaluate
>   $$q(t)=A\cdot (2000t)^t\cdot e^{-2000t}$$ when $q(0)=4000$?

I just can't get around $(2000\cdot0)^0$.

Comment: where ist the differential equation? I would use $0^0=1$ otherwise, you can't determine $A$ from your assumptions.

Comment: The equation is $\frac{dq}{dt}=1000 \cdot 2^{t}$

Answer (score 1):

So you want to evaluate $q(t)=A(2000t)^te^{-2000t}$ when $q(0)=4000$?

You have $$q(0)=A(2000\cdot0)^0e^{-2000\cdot0}=A\cdot1\cdot1=A$$

So now using the fact that $q(0)=4000$ you get $$q(0)=A=4000$$
So $A=4000$

Comment: Please see my rolled-over edit. There are typos in your question and you should use $\cdot$ (`\cdot`) for multiplication instead of parentheses, that makes it look much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks! I've wondered how to do that!

Answer (score 1):

The critical observation is the function $f(t)=t^t$, $t>0$, extends continuous to $t=0$, and it could be defined as $f(0)=1$, as
$$
\lim_{t\searrow 0}t^t=\exp(t\log t)=\exp (0)=1,
$$
since $\lim_{t\searrow 0}t\log t=0.$

Once we know that then as $q(t)=A\cdot 2000^t\cdot t^t \cdot\mathrm{e}^{-2000t}$, then
$$
q(0)=A\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1=A.
$$
Hence $q(0)=4000$ if and only if $A=4000$.

Comment: I've noticed people using $exp(0)$ instead of $e^0$. Is it a personal preference for doing this? Or some mathematical reason for this?

Comment: I use both symbols. The only advantage of $\exp$ is that we avoid by using it small fonts. For example, $e^{e^a}$ versus $\exp(\exp(a))$.

Comment: That makes sense. I assumed it was just a personal preference, but I wanted to make sure it wasn't some advanced mathematical reason that I didn't know. Thanks for your response!